# Django form use queryset in constructor, how to recreate form, when I change site language?

Tags: django, caching

I create form that allows user to choose airport and then dynamically limits airport terminal choises. In page it llooks like this:

```
Airport: 
<select name="address_form-0-airport" id="id_address_form-0-airport">
<option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
<option value="10">Sheremetyevo</option>
<option value="11">Bykovo</option>
<option value="12">Vnukovo</option>
<option value="13">Domodedovo</option>
</select></br>

Terminal: 
<select name="address_form-0-terminal" id="id_address_form-0-terminal">
<option data-parent="-" value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
<option data-parent="Sheremetyevo" value="30">Terminal B</option>
<option data-parent="Sheremetyevo" value="31">Terminal C</option>
<option data-parent="Sheremetyevo" value="32">Terminal D</option>
```

To create terminal choises I inherit Select widget. It use {terminal:airport} dictionary to render options with data-parent attribute which is airport name:

```
class TerminalSelect(forms.Select):
    terminal_ports={}

    def render_option(self, selected_choices, option_value, option_label):
        if option_label in self.terminal_ports.keys():
            airport=self.terminal_ports[option_label]
        else:
            airport="-"
        option_value = force_unicode(option_value)
        selected_html = (option_value in selected_choices) and u' selected="selected"' or ''
        return u'<option data-parent="%s" value="%s"%s>%s</option>' % (
            airport, escape(option_value), selected_html,
            conditional_escape(force_unicode(option_label)))
```

And here is form code, where field is declarend and dictionary {terminal:airport} created:

```
class AdvancedAddressForm(Form):        
    airports_queryset=Airport.objects.all()
    airport=forms.ModelChoiceField(required=False,queryset=airports_queryset)    
    terminals_queryset=AirportTerminal.objects.all()
    terminal_ports={}
    for terminal in terminals_queryset:            terminal_ports[force_unicode(terminal.name)]=force_unicode(terminal.airport.name)
    terminal_select_widget=TerminalSelect()    
    terminal_select_widget.terminal_ports=terminal_ports
    terminal=forms.ModelChoiceField(required=False,queryset=terminals_queryset,widget=terminal_select_widget)
```

It works until I change language. When I change language, airport names change on form, but {terminal:airport} dictionary stay unchanged. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble is, you're not doing anything in the "constructor". You're doing everything at class definition time.

All that logic actually needs to go inside the `__init__` method of the form:

```
class AdvancedAddressForm(Form):        
    airports_queryset = Airport.objects.all()
    airport = forms.ModelChoiceField(required=False, queryset=airports_queryset)    
    terminals_queryset = AirportTerminal.objects.all()
    terminal = forms.ModelChoiceField(required=False, queryset=terminals_queryset)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AdvancedAddressForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        terminal_ports = {}
        for terminal in self.fields['terminal'].queryset:
            terminal_ports[force_unicode(terminal.name)] = force_unicode(terminal.airport.name)
        terminal_select_widget = TerminalSelect()    
        terminal_select_widget.terminal_ports = terminal_ports
        self.fields['terminal'].widget = terminal_select_widget
```

Comment: thanks! One problem is: when I create widget in constructor and then set field's widget it shows on form empty select field. When I init widget in class and then set it's dictionary in constructor, all works fine.